# How to work on specific artboards with Illustrator script?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to draw objects (though scripting) on specific artboards (and layers), but I can't find any example. I thought this part of code would be enough, but objects still appear on the first artboard.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
doc.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex (1);
```

Thanks for help

Fransua

Comment: Have you tried a different artboard i.e. something like `doc.artboards.setActiveArtboardIndex(2);`?

Comment: With index at 2, there is an error when I run  the script. With 0 and 1 (I have 2 artboards in my illustrator) no error, but impossible to draw inside the second artboard.

Comment: We may need to see more of your code to find the problem